# Getting all Polite numbers below a certain number

Tags: c++, numbers

I am trying to write a C++ program that displays all polite numbers that are below a certain number. So for example, if someone were to enter 6, then I would want to print out 3,5,6. I would want to print out 3,5,6,7,9 if the number 9 was to be entered.

I've already done the two for loops. I just can't figure out how to test it for all consecutive number combinations, to get the polite numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "Welcome to the polite numbers program." << endl;

int upValue;
int num1, num2;

cout << "What is the upper value? "; //Ask user for upper limit
cin >> upValue; //Stores user input into upValue

while (upValue < 1) //Validate user input of upper limit
{
    cout << "What is the upper value? (must be an integer > 0) ";
    cin >> upValue;
}

for (num1 = 1; num1 <= upValue; num1++) { //Looping from 1 to upper variable


for (num2 = num1 + 1; num2 <= upValue; num2++) { //Looping from 2 to upper

//Something goes here to get all polite numbers below a certain number.
}
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: break the problem into smaller subproblems. I.e. create a function to test if a number is polite `bool is_polite(int)`. Then check all numbers 1-upValue if they are polite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break this down into two smaller problems.

Here's an example of an implementation. There are likely far more efficient ways to do this, but this should give you an idea of what needs to be done.

```cpp
// calculate the sum of all integers between "start" and "end" inclusive.
// hint: the sum of integers between 1 and n is "n(n + 1) / 2".
int sum_between(int start, int end)
{
    return (end * (end + 1) - start * (start - 1)) / 2;
}

// determine if a number polite
bool number_is_polite(int num)
{
    // a little shortcut, we know any number less than 3
    // cannot be polite
    if (num <= 2)
        return false;

    // get the starting point, which must be at least 2 away
    // from the target number
    for (int start = 1; start <= num - 2; start++)
    {
        // get the ending point, which must be at least 1 away
        for (int end = start + 1; end <= num - 1; end++)
        {
            // return true if the sum of integers between start/end
            // inclusive is equal to the target number
            if (sum_between(start, end) == num)
                return true;
        }
    }

    // we searched all consecutive integer subsets but nothing
    // seemed to sum to the target number
    return false;
}
```

Now we can complete your code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

// < insert functions from above >

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the polite numbers program." << endl;

    int upValue;

    cout << "What is the upper value? "; //Ask user for upper limit
    cin >> upValue; //Stores user input into upValue

    while (upValue < 1) //Validate user input of upper limit
    {
        cout << "What is the upper value? (must be an integer > 0) ";
        cin >> upValue;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= upValue; i++)
    {
        if (number_is_polite(i))
            cout << i << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hint: There is a much, much faster politeness test than what is shown here, but I'll leave that for you to find. I implemented the naive approach just to demonstrate how one might tackle this problem.

Comment: Thanks, dreamlax. I actually tried to implement a faster approach after researching polite numbers. But for this assignment anyway, I have to use what has been taught in class so far.